# python removing empty objects in a array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Im new to python and was playing with array and found problem

```
array =  [{'hsp': 24, 'lsp': 22, 'timefrom': '00:00', 'timeto': '23:59'},
          {}, {}, {}]
```

i wanted to remove empty object and result should look like this  `[{'hsp': 24, 'lsp': 22, 'timefrom': '00:00', 'timeto': '23:59'}]`

```
for day,value in array.iteritems():
    if not value:
    continue
    print array
```

found this could not help

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with `newlist = [el for el in array if el]`. By the way: that's a list, not an array

Comment: `array[:] = [d for d in array if d]`, that will also remove any Falsey values like None, 0 etc..

Comment: thank you.......... i appreciate you reply

Comment: If you only want to remove empty iterables `array[:] = [d for d in array if not isinstance(d, collections.Iterable) or d ]` so  `array =  [{'hsp': 24, 'lsp': 22, 'timefrom': '00:00', 'timeto': '23:59'},
          {}, {}, {},0, None]` will become `[{'lsp': 22, 'timefrom': '00:00', 'hsp': 24, 'timeto': '23:59'}, 0, None]`

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
array = [{'hsp': 24, 'lsp': 22, 'timefrom': '00:00', 'timeto': '23:59'}, {}, {}, {}]
edited_array = [x for x in array if x]
print(edited_array)
```

**Output**

```
[{'hsp': 24, 'lsp': 22, 'timefrom': '00:00', 'timeto': '23:59'}]
```

In Python, empty dictionaries, `{}`, and empty lists, `[]`, evaluate to `False`. The above list comprehension adds each item in `array` to `edited_array` if it is not `False` (ie not empty).

Comment: im little confused can you brief why x [x for x in array if x] present before for.........

Comment: Probably best to take a look at some of the list comprehension examples here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html